# How can I reference an Excel worksheet without hardcoding its name in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a Macro for excel for copying one excel sheet to another excel sheet.

*This is working:*

```
Function CopyFile()

   Dim Wb1 As Workbook
   Dim Wb2 As Workbook
   Dim ws1 As Worksheet
   Dim ws2 As Worksheet

   Set Wb1 = ActiveWorkbook   
   Set ws1 = Wb1.Worksheets("Task")
   Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open("D:\Outlook\dest.xlsx")

   ws1.Copy Wb2.Worksheets(1)

   Wb2.Save
   Wb2.Close
   Wb1.Activate   

End Function
```

But i don't want to use a hard coded string to get the sheet name  **Set ws1 = Wb1.Worksheets("Task")**. Instead want to use the function argument.

Following piece of code does not work:

```
Function CopyFile(name As String)

   Dim Wb1 As Workbook
   Dim Wb2 As Workbook
   Dim ws1 As Worksheet
   Dim ws2 As Worksheet

   Set Wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

   Set ws1 = Wb1.Worksheets(name)
   Set Wb2 = Workbooks.Open("D:\Outlook\dest.xlsx")
   ws1.Copy Wb2.Worksheets(1)

   Wb2.Save
   Wb2.Close
   Wb1.Activate

End Function
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you get an error? Your code looks fine to me, except of course if the sheet does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me.  If you pass a name that doesn't exist, you'll get an error.  Maybe

```
Function CopyFile(sSheetName As String)

    Dim wbSource As Workbook
    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Dim wsSource As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet

    Set wbSource = ActiveWorkbook

    On Error Resume Next
        Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets(sSheetName)
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not wsSource Is Nothing Then
        Set wbDest = Workbooks.Open("D:\Outlook\dest.xlsx")
        wsSource.Copy wbDest.Worksheets(1)

        wbDest.Save
        wbDest.Close
        wbSource.Activate
    End If

End Function
```

The work "Name" is a reserved word in VBA.  You can still use it as a variable/argument name, but you probably shouldn't.